If you're disqualified from being a director of a company in India (DIN disqualified) can you remain director of a company in England?
Someone I know has been DIN disqualified in India, but has continued to hold a directorship in the UK, and even conducted business in India for the UK company whilst disqualified.
EDIT: I asked a separate question that overlapped with this one, so have deleted that and edited this one:
Let's say the director in question, John Smith, runs Generic IT Services Limited (an IT services company) in the UK.  He and his wife are co-directors.  He wants to do business with some contacts in India, but rather than doing that business through Generic IT Services he launches a new company, doing the same work but in India, called Generic IT Services Private Limited.  He and three Indian nationals are co-directors, his wife not involved.  A few years later, Generic IT Services Private Limited is struck off in India for financial misconduct, and Smith his three Indian national co-directors are DIN disqualified for 10yrs.  Smith though, remains a director of the UK-registered Generic IT Services Limited and even travels to India to do business through that UK-registered company.
Q1) Does DIN disqualification in India mean you have to give up directorships in other countries?
Q2) Can you hold a directorship in the UK and conduct business in India for that company whilst DIN disqualified in India?
Q3) Can you set-up a new company in a foreign country (India in this case) with an almost identical name to your UK company, doing basically the same work, with the UK company unaffected when your foreign company is struck off for financial misconduct?

Note the semantical distinction between "[being director of a company] in India" vs "being director of [a company in India]". Also note the distinction between letting go of a directorship of a non-Indian company, being prohibited from your company conducting business in India, and Indian companies being prohibited from doing business with your company when you are its director. For example, what if an Indian company comes to your London office to do business with you? These kinds of distinctions will matter very much for the question that you're trying to ask.

united-kingdom
Section 159A(1) of the Companies Act 2006 provides:

A person may not be appointed a director of a company if the person is
disqualified under the directors disqualification legislation (see
subsection (2)).

Section 169A provides:

A person who has been appointed as a director of a company ceases to
hold office by virtue of that appointment if the person becomes
disqualified under the directors disqualification legislation (see
section 159A(2)).

The disqualification legislation is different depending on what jurisdiction the company is registered in.
england-and-walesscotland
The relevant disqualification legislation for companies registered under these jurisdictions is set out in Part 1 of the table in Section 159A(2). They are as follows:



P is subject to a disqualification order or undertaking under the Company Directors Disqualification Act 1986.

This requires an order to have been made under the 1986 Act. Not applicable.



Any of the circumstances mentioned in section 11 of the Company Directors Disqualification Act 1986 (bankruptcy etc) apply to P.

Section 11 relates to bankruptcy and related matters within the UK. Not applicable.



P is subject to director disqualification sanctions within the meaning of section 11A of the Company Directors Disqualification Act 1986.

Section 11A requires the director to be subject to disqualification sanctions under UK legislation (set out in subsection 4). Not applicable.



Section 12 of the Company Directors Disqualification Act 1986 (disabilities on revocation of administration order against an individual) applies to P.

Section 12 also relates to bankruptcy within the UK. Not applicable.



P is subject to a disqualification order or undertaking mentioned in section 12A or 12B of the Company Directors Disqualification Act 1986 (recognition of Northern Ireland disqualification orders and undertakings).

Sections 12A and 12B extend some of the above provisions so that a person who is subject to disqualification under Northern Ireland legislation is also disqualified in the rest of the UK. Not applicable.


We can conclude therefore that disqualification under Indian company law is not relevant for the purposes of disqualification under UK law for companies registered in England and Wales or Scotland.
northern-ireland
Part 2 of the table provides for similar rules relating to companies registered in Northern Ireland. I won't analyse them here, but if you're interested in this jurisdiction then you can view the table at Section 159A(2).
india
My answer is only concerned whether or not the director is considered disqualified under UK law. It may be that there are consequences under Indian law for a director who is disqualified there to act as a director abroad. I'm not able to address that.

Would the "may not be appointed" part mean "may not get a new appointment" or does it also imply "has to give up any pre-existing appointments"? If someone is director of companies A and B, and gets disqualified for something related to A, I'd read that as "may not be appointed to a new company C, but can keep their position at B".

@GuntramBlohm Good point. An existing director automatically ceases to be one upon being disqualified. I've edited the relevant legislation into the answer.
